# Retrieving JSON data using dataTaskWithRequest: not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsdata, nsurlsessiondatatask

I'm using the following code to get the data from server. It works fine when using the below code.

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:URL options:NSDataReadingUncached error:&error];

if(error==nil){

    NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization
                          JSONObjectWithData:data
                          options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                          error:&error];
}
```

It successfully converting the data to json format.

But when I tried to get the data using below format,

```
NSDictionary *proxyDict = @{
                            @"HTTPEnable"  : [NSNumber numberWithInt:1],
                            (NSString *)kCFStreamPropertyHTTPProxyHost  : proxyHost,
                            (NSString *)kCFStreamPropertyHTTPProxyPort  : proxyPort,
                            (NSString *)kCFProxyUsernameKey : hostUserName,
                            (NSString *)kCFProxyPasswordKey : hostPassword,

                            @"HTTPSEnable" : [NSNumber numberWithInt:1],
                            (NSString *)kCFStreamPropertyHTTPSProxyHost : proxyHost,
                            (NSString *)kCFStreamPropertyHTTPSProxyPort : proxyPort,
                            (NSString *)kCFProxyUsernameKey : hostUserName,
                            (NSString *)kCFProxyPasswordKey : hostPassword,
                            };

NSURLSessionConfiguration *sessionConfig = [NSURLSessionConfiguration ephemeralSessionConfiguration];
sessionConfig.connectionProxyDictionary = proxyDict;

NSURLSessionConfiguration *sessionConfig = [NSURLSessionConfiguration ephemeralSessionConfiguration];
sessionConfig.connectionProxyDictionary = proxyDict;

NSURLSession *defaultSession = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration: sessionConfig delegate: nil delegateQueue: [NSOperationQueue mainQueue]];

__block NSDictionary *returnJsonDictionary;
__block NSError *error1;

NSURLSessionDataTask *task = [defaultSession dataTaskWithRequest:URLrequest completionHandler:
                              ^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
                                  NSLog(@"NSURLSession got the response [%@]", response);
                                  NSLog(@"NSURLSession got the data [%@]", data);

NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error1];
```

It returns

```
<HTML><HEAD>
<meta http-equiv=pragma content=nocache>
<META HTTP-EQUIV=Expires CONTENT=-1>
<SCRIPT>
    location.href="https://myHostAddress:port/httpclient.html"
</SCRIPT>
</HEAD><BODY>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: The response format is not correct, ask web guy.

Comment: The problem comes from response parsing

Comment: If it is not then `NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization
                          JSONObjectWithData:data
                          options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                          error:&error];` this line also should get that error right

Comment: Is data from `NSURLSessionDataTask` the same as the one from `dataWithContentsOfURL:`? Also check that `NSString *jsonStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:theData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];` seems legit (for both case of data and if it's the same).

Comment: I think its problem with the response you're getting, It's not an NSDictionary i guess..

Comment: @Larme - Question updated please have a look

Comment: It's HTML, not JSON. You may want to add accepted-content to JSON in `URLrequest` which is coming from ([URLrequest setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];[URLrequest setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];`

Comment: Definitly server side issue. Or your url request is different, hence getting a different result.

Answer (score 0):

Uses this it Works fine.

```
 NSURL *myUrl=[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=jack+johnson&entity=musicVideo"];
        NSURLRequest *myRequest=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:myUrl];

        NSURLSessionConfiguration *mySessionConfiguration=[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];

        NSURLSession *mySession=[NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:mySessionConfiguration delegate:nil delegateQueue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]];

        NSURLSessionDataTask *myDataTask=[mySession dataTaskWithRequest:myRequest completionHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable data, NSURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error)
        {
            NSDictionary *myDict=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];

             NSLog(@"the value is dictionary is %@",myDict);

        }];

        [myDataTask resume];
```